# Quelles seraient des exemples de manières de formuler la phrase citée dans le corps de la question de manière plus claire et plus précise:

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quelles seraient quelques propositions de formulations pour mieux exprimer ma pensée de sorte qu'elle soit plus claire, plus précise, plus concise et présente une meilleure mise en rapport des idées.

J'étais en train de rouler sur la rue des Outardes quand un conducteur venant en sens inverse a brusquement coupé ma voie à l'intersection du McDonald's, causant un accident entre mon véhicule et le sien. Il n'a pas respecté ma priorité de passage avant de s'engager sur l'intersection pour tourner à gauche, ce qui constitue une manœuvre irresponsable et une infraction au code de la route. Il faut croire qu'il était pressé d'aller commander un trio big mac!

Comment formuleriez-vous l'idée que le texte véhicule, par exemple à un policier ou à votre courtier en assurance pour faire état d'un accident de la route impliquant vous et un autre automobiliste.

La texte doit comprendre le fait que mon véhicule a percuté celui du fautif.

Comment: Note : bon usage du participe présent cette fois-ci ! (conséquence).  https://www.memoireonline.com/04/08/1029/m_approche-exploratoire-relation-consequence-description-implementation33.html

Comment: Un remarque ; juste mon opinion bien sûr. Je crois qu'avec les titres des vos questions ce n'est pas du tout de se répérer lorsque l'on utilise la recherche de FSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Il vaut mieux dire tout de suite qu'on conduit une voiture.
2. « L'intersection du MacDonald's » est du langage familier.
   « Causant un accident entre mon véhicule … » devrait suffire mais « entrant en collision …» est un choix possible.
3. Manœuvre irresponsable et infraction sont des faits dont les policiers sont très conscients dès qu'on leur dit qu'on vous a coupé la route, donc à mon avis il est inutile de mentionner ça.
4. Le trait d'esprit final est acceptable dans un rapport de vive voix et dans certaines circonstances plutôt rares, mais absolument à rejeter dans un rapport écrit.

- J'étais au volant de mon auto, rue des Outardes, quand à la hauteur de l'intersection où se trouve le MacDonald's un automobiliste venant en sens inverse m'a brusquement coupé la voie, entrant en collision avec mon véhicule. ( Il faut croire qu'il était pressé d'aller commander un trio big mac!)

Answer (score 1):

Cela me semble presque parfait, mais :

"a coupé ma voie" -> "*m'a* coupé *la* voie/la route" est plus idiomatique. A moins que "ma voie" serve à insister sur le segment spécifique sur lequel on se trouvait, sur une route de 3 voies ou plus, par exemple la voie de droite par opposition à celle du milieu, etc.